# Alfresco with LDAP, changing password of a user in Alfresco intefrace

Tags: ldap, alfresco, alfresco-ldap

I have successfully added ldap-ad to Alfresco. Now when i am creating a user in AD, it is synchronized with Alfresco and i got an Alfresco user. The question is, if a user Bob (that has been sync from AD) changes his password (in Alfresco interface), in which authentication system the password will be changed, Alfresco or AD?

If the password will be changed in AD, then i have no other querstion, but as far as i know, there is only one direction sync, from AD to Alfresco, so Alfresco cant access the AD passwords and change them. Does this mean, that Alfresco will create a password for Bob and store it in its own authentication system and now Bob can loggin with alfresco and AD passwords (new and old)? And most important question: How to avoid that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alfresco uses an authentication chain concept. That means you can configure more than 1 system for the authentication and if a user tries to authenticate Alfresco steps thru the configured chain and tries one system after the other until the user has been authenticated successfully or if the auth fails on the last chain member the auth attempt is assumed as failed.

Alfresco brings it's own authentication subsystem to create and store users locally in the repo db with passwords. Locally created users like admin are stored in the local subsystem `alfrescoNtlm` which you could find in the node browser in the `user://alfrescoUserStore/` store. That store is for the authentication of internal users only.

"users" you see and manage in the Alfresco UI are of type `cm:person` stored in the main store `workspace://SpacesStore` (/sys:system/sys:people/) but do not contain any password at all.

The ldap sync only creates users in the `workspace://SpacesStore` under `/sys:system/sys:people/`and once a user tries to login Alfresco walks thru the `authentication.chain` which may look like in production:
`kerberos1:kerberos,ldap-ad2:ldap-ad,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm`.

Alfresco Share only provides the user a "Change Password" dialog if the user is found in the local alfrescoUserStore. Alfresco does never change a password in any other system.

To test whether you have understood everything: What happens if a user `max` exists in the AD and in the local alfrescoUserStore and changes it's password in the Alfresco UI? ;-)

Comment: This user will have 2 password? :)

Comment: more or less yes: the user `max` would be able to login with either the ad or local password.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using LDAP for authentication, then the passwords will never store in Alfresco. Passwords will be stored in LDAP and and it will be linked with Alfresco by their email or usernames.